# Читач/письменник чи може "писач" якийсь?

Tags: вибір-слова

Натрапив на таку [задачу](http://blog.golovatyi.info/category/programming/problems/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%96-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/):

> Є певний ресурс (черга, файл, таблиця, тощо) з якого одночасно може
>   читати довільна кількість нитей-**читачів**, але писати одночасно може
>   лише одна нить-**письменник**.
>
> Треба реалізувати сихнхронізацію цього ресурсу.

Логічно було б читач-писач, але пошук "писача" в інеті позитивних результатів не дав. Чи таки письменник?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Як синоніми до письменник можна навести такі слова: літератор, літерат, письмовець, письмак, писака.

Також [тут](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=writer&dicts=all&highlight=on) можна знайти такі переклади:

> **writer** [ˈraɪtə, *амер*. ˈraɪt̬(ə)r] *n*
>      1) письме́нник, письме́нниця; а́втор, а́вторка
>
> **writer** = ['raɪtə] **1.** запи́сувач **2.** реда́ктор (*у групі документування
>   розробок*) **3.** а́втор, письме́нник
>
> **writer** (*комп*.) запи́сувач, запи́сувальний при́стрій

І [тут](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=reader&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> **reader** = ['ri:də] **1.** чита́ч (*людина*) **2.** зчи́тувач, чита́льний при́стрій **3.** програ́ма чита́ння (зчи́тування)

Отже, можливо, **зчитувач/записувач.**